# graphics not displaying after appropriate event

Tags: java, user-interface, events

So, I've been studying GUI's and event handling, and I make this code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class drawing extends JComponent {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.draw(new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100));
    }
}

class TwoButtons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoButtons two = new TwoButtons();
        two.go();
    }
    JButton button1 = new JButton("button 1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("button 2");
    drawing D = new drawing();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("title");
    void go() {

        button1.addActionListener(new button1Action());

        button2.addActionListener(new button2Action());

        frame.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button1);
        frame.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, button2);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(900, 900);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class button1Action implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            frame.add(D);
        }
    }

    class button2Action implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            button2.setText("action 2");
        }
    }
}
```

So this code generates two buttons at SOUTH and another at NORTH of JFrame.

It should display a square as soon as user clicks `button1`, but it displays a Square after both `button1` and `button2` are clicked (first `button1` and then `button2`).

Why is this happening? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is lazy.  When dynamically updating the UI, you need to instruct it when you want it to perform and update pass, for example...

```
class button1Action implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        frame.add(D);
        frame.revalidate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

This triggers a layout and paint pass after `D` is added to the frame

Comment: Okay, thank you. Just one question, what would be more efficient in place of swing

Comment: I don't understand?  The most efficient use of the above would be at the point your satisfied the UI needs to be updated, performing a layout pass is not always a simple process or fast process, you should only do it when you're satisfied that the layout has stabilised

Comment: okay, but as you said swing is lazy, what should we use in place of it?

Comment: Nothing - this is designed this way, if you're making a large number of changes to the UI, you don't want the API running off performing layout calculations and scheduling paint cycles for every little change, it's inefficient.  Instead, you make all your changes and then instruct Swing that it should update, by calling `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container you've changed.  This is done for efficiency reasons